# Wordpress permalink not linking to content.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress custom theme from scratch. I've managed to get a custom grid display to work in index.php. Each post shows an image with the post's title and category as subtitle. Here's index.php code:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center Site-content" style="padding:60px; padding-top:100px;">
    <?php
    $counter = 1; //start counter

    $grids = 2; //Grids per row

    query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=12');


    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>
            <?php
//Show the left hand side column
            if ($counter == 1) :
                ?>   
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;" alt=""></a>
                    <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                     <?php
                     foreach ((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                         echo "<h6>".$category->category_nicename. "</h6>";   
                     }
                     ?>
                </div>    
                <?php
//Show the right hand side column
            elseif ($counter == $grids) :
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;" alt=""></a>
                    <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                     <?php
                     // heres just the name and permalink:
                     foreach ((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                         echo "<h6>".$category->category_nicename. "</h6>";   
                     }
                     ?>
                </div>   
                <?php
                $counter = 0;
            endif;
            ?>
            <?php
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The post's thumbnail contains a link to the post's permalink, that should link to content.php. Here's content.php:

```html
<div class="container" style="padding:100px;">
 <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
        <?php
        foreach ((get_the_category()) as $category) {
            echo "<h5>" . $category->category_nicename . "</h5>";
        }
        ?>
        <h5> / <?php the_date(); ?> </h5>
        <h5> <?php the_content(); ?> </h5>
   </div>
```

The problem is that when I click on the index.php thumbnail, it links to a smaller version of itself, instead of the content.php page. My guess is that I need to tell the permalink where to go but I can't really find where to put this configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, `the_permalink()` or `get_permalink()` returns the single page URL for a post or page. It's a WordPress [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) that single post pages will load the `single.php` file.

You've two options here,

1) Copy your code from `content.php` to `single.php` and you'll be good to go. Of course you need to include `get_header()` and `get_footer()` to make the page load properly.

2) In your `single.php` inside the loop, you can include `content.php` as template part. The following goes in your `single.php`, replacing the loop.

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content' );
endwhile;
```

Also, in the code above, I am assuming your `content.php` is placed in the theme directory root.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you! Now, i'm only having trouble applying my external css sheet to the content generated but I guess that's another story.